Is $\{0\} \times K$ a field?
If $K$ is a field, then $\{0\} \times K$ is a field? I think it is because clearly is a ring because is direct product of 2 rings. And every element $(0,b)$ with $b \ne 0$ has the inverse $(0,b^{-1})$ and $(0,b)(0,b^{-1})=(0,1)$ where $0$ is identity element of $\{0\}$ and $1$ is identity element of $K$. It's ok?

Sure, it's trivially isomorphic to $K$. So is ${}\times K$

This is an answer to the question, not just a comment. Comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See How do comments work for more information. Therefore, please post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list.

@MartinBrandenburg that comment by JZ is a gem and the only contribution here that makes this post worth reading.

Doesn't change that posting answers in a comment violates the site rules and the purpose of the site.

Only a comment - the result should be already familiar from the analogous fact for groups. We have $1\times G\cong G$, in the context of the direct product of groups. Here $1={e}$ is the trivial group.

For any ring $R$, $$R\times\lbrace{0}\rbrace\cong R$$
$$\lbrace{0}\rbrace\times R\cong R$$
The maps
$$(a,0)\mapsto a$$
$$(0,a)\mapsto a$$
are the respective ring isomorphisms.
Thus it works for any field $K$ as well.
